# how to use or operator in if statement with more than one conditions

Tags: c

I was hoping if there is a way so that in 'if-statement' if we are using more than one 'or' operator can we assign value to a variable which will use that particular condition in if-statement.

```
if(sum1>15 || sum2>15 || sum3 >15)
{
    // I want sum = sum1 if the first condition satisfies, 
    // sum=sum2 if the second ,
    // sum=sum3 if the third, instead of given code below.
}

if(sum1>15)
    sum=sum1
if(sum2>15)
    sum=sum2
if(sum3>15)
    sum=sum3
```

Comment: What if more than one of the conditions is satisfied?  Do you want the last to be used (matching the effect of your multiple `if` statements)? The first? The largest? Something else?

Comment: What's wrong with the three if statements? Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
sum3 > 15 && (sum = sum3, 1) || sum2 > 15 && (sum = sum2, 1) || sum1 > 15 && (sum = sum1, 1)
```

would do this, at the expense of obfuscation (MISRA bans this type of thing due to the assignment side-effect in a short circuit operator). Here I'm exploiting the *short-circuiting* property of `&&` and `||`: the assignment only happens if the left hand argument is 1. Furthermore the value of the evaluated assignment expressions will never be zero. (In your particular case the `, 1` are superfluous but is there so we don't rely on the fact that 15 is positive.)

In other words, all rather flaky. Using the 3 `if`s is far, far clearer.

Comment: One might add that this would fail if 15 was a non-positive number and any of sum1, sum2 and sum3 were zero.

Comment: @klutt: Although it's difficult to argue that 15 is not positive, I've added the old idiom from yesteryear.

Comment: I was unclear. What I meant was that this construct would not work if you changed 15 to a non-positive number.

Comment: Had to check if `&&` and `||` implies a sequence point, but they do so I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
sum = sum3>15 ? sum3 : (sum2>15 ? sum2 : (sum1>15 ? sum1 : sum));
```

The parenthesis are optional. They are just there to make it clearer what's going on. However, I would definitely recommend your three if statements over this.

> I was hoping if there is a way so that in 'if-statement' if we are using more than one 'or' operator can we assign value to a variable which will use that particular condition in if-statement.

If you are unwilling to modify the if statement, this is completely impossible. When you enter the body of the if statment, the only thing you can be sure of is that the condition as a whole evaluated to true.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is almost certainly to rewrite the code using a loop:

```
int sum[n] = ... ;
int result = 0;

for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  if(sum[i] > 15)
  {
    result = sum[i];
    break;
  }
}
```